# Running NetBeans, have permission to read and write to the directory, but listFiles() returns null even though there are files in the directory

Tags: java, netbeans

I am running on Mac Big Sur. I installed NetBeans on the platform. It's possible my problems are related to Big Sur.

Here is my code:

˚˚˚

```
String ginsburgDirectory =       "/Users/alberthembd/Documents/Documents/Ginsburg/Real_Edition_of_Ginsburg_Bible/1)Actual_Ginsburg_Text";
File f = new File(ginsburgDirectory);
final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String tempWordString = "";
String chapterString = "";
String convertedChapterString = "";
boolean chapterFlag = false;
int value = 0;
 
if (f.isDirectory()) {
     System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(f.getName());
    System.out.println("It is a directory: " + f.isDirectory());
    System.out.println("Can read " + f.canRead());
    System.out.println("Can write " + f.canWrite());
    try {
    System.out.println("Listing of files: " + f.list());
    } catch(SecurityException s) { s.printStackTrace(); }
    System.out.println("No Security Exception.");
    File[] listFiles = f.listFiles();
    System.out.println(f.listFiles().toString());
```

˚˚˚

The calls to `getAbsolutePath()`, `getDirectory()`, `canRead()`, and `canWrite()` all return true. The code blows up on `System.out.println(f.listFiles().toString())`, because I get a `NullPointerException` even though there are thirty-nine files in the directory. Below is a listing of the files:

```
Alberthembd@MacBook-Pro 1)Actual_Ginsburg_Text % ls
01_Genesis.txt      15_Hosea.txt        29_Proverbs.txt
02_Exodus.txt       16_Joel.txt     30_Ruth.txt
03_Leviticus.txt    17_Amos.txt     31_Song_of_Solomon.txt
04_Numbers.txt      18_Obadiah.txt      32_Ecclesiastes.txt
05_Deuteronomy.txt  19_Jonah.txt        33_Lamentations.txt
06_Joshua.txt       20_Micah.txt        34_Esther.txt
07_Judges.txt       21_Nahum.txt        35_Daniel.txt
08_I_Samuel.txt     22_Habakkuk.txt     36_Ezra.txt
09_II_Samuel.txt    23_Zephaniah.txt    37_Nehemiah.txt
10_I_Kings.txt      24_Haggai.txt       38_I_Chronicles.txt
11_II_Kings.txt     25_Zechariah.txt    39_II_Chronicles.txt
12_Isaiah.txt       26_Malachi.txt      Ginsburg_Source
13_Jeremiah.txt     27_Psalms.txt       ב) נביאים
14_Ezekiel.txt      28_Job.txt      ג) כתובים
```

I run as myself, and so far as I can tell, I have admin privileges. I used `chmod 777` to grant wide-open privileges on all the files in the directory.

I am thinking there is a problem with NetBeans; that it has to be granted some sort of privilege to read the files on my Mac. If so, how would I grant such privileges? Would it be in a **.conf** file in NetBeans?

A previous Java program I wrote using the same logic worked beautifully but is also no longer working.

Comment: what happens if you interate over all files and print the name of each? `for (File file : listFiles) { System.out.println(listFiles.getAbsoluteFile().getName()); }`

Comment: It doesn't work. This code returns null. System.out.println("Listing of files: " + f.list());

Comment: [1] `getAbsolutePath()` returns a `String` so it can't be returning `true`. Rather than describing the output, paste the actual output from running your code. [2] Update the question's tags to specify the versions of Java and NetBeans. [3] Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Readers should be able to copy/paste your code, changing only the directory path, in order to test it.

Comment: OK, Skomisa. Sorry for the delay - I had to sleep. Here is the output from my code.

Process[pid=2598, exitValue=0]
/Users/alberthembd/Documents/Documents/Ginsburg/Real_Edition_of_Ginsburg_Bible/1)Actual_Ginsburg_Text
1)Actual_Ginsburg_Text
It is a directory: true
Can read true
Can write true
Listing of files: null
No Security Exception.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "java.io.File.listFiles()" is null

Comment: You can see that System.out.println prints the full path: "/Users/alberthembd/Documents/Documents/Ginsburg/Real_Edition_of_Ginsburg_Bible/1)Actual_Ginsburg_Text 1)Actual_Ginsburg_Text".

isDirectory() correctly returns that this is a directory. canRead() returns true. But the debug statement as to whether it can write the listing of files in that directory returns null. And then, this code blows up, because it gets a nullPointerException:

"System.out.println(f.listFiles().toString());"

So - Java knows it's a directory, it says it has read and write privileges, but it cannot list.

Comment: "1] getAbsolutePath() returns a String so it can't be returning true." It's not getAbsolutePath() that is returning true. It's "canRead()". But "getAbsolutePath()" returns the right directory, and "isDirectory()" correctly identifies it as a directory.

Comment: Here is the code:

    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(f.getName());
        System.out.println("It is a directory: " + f.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("Can read " + f.canRead());
        System.out.println("Can write " + f.canWrite())
        System.out.println("Listing of files: " + f.list())
        File[] listFiles = f.listFiles();
        System.out.println(f.listFiles().toString());

Comment: This code is not running in Android. It's running on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: OK. I have the answer. If I run the programme in bash, it works! listFiles() works fine! The odd quirk now is that now, in order to open a FileInputStream, I have to name the full AbsolutePathName of the file. Didn't have to do that before.

It appears to me that NetBeans needs to update to accommodate the latest changes made to file reading in Mac Big Sur.

Comment: I was running it in NetBeans before.